# The right way to use constructors when using Streamwriter

Tags: c#, function, constructor

My code as follows:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8081);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("- Waiting for a connection..... .");
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        while (true)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.");
            //TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                int recv = 0;
                foreach (byte b in buffer)
                {
                    if (b != 0)
                    {
                        recv++;
                    }
                }
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);


                //
                var result = data.Split(new string[] { cr }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

               
                sw.WriteLine("Hello Client, This is server");
                sw.Flush();
```

sw.WriteLine works just fine here, but when I try to call it from another function

```
 public static void Send()
        {
           
          sw.Writeline("Sending this from send function");  
            
        }
```

I get an error saying
(Error  9   The name 'sw' does not exist in the current context).

I couldn't figure out the right way to call it since sw StreamWriter uses stream() and stream uses (client) while the client uses (listener), this got beyond my very humble understanding of c#, I  spent 2 days trying and researching before posting but with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass sw from the Main method as a parameter of the Send method: `public static void Send(StreamWriter sw)` and call `Send(sw)` from the Main. Is that you need? Some reading suggestions: [C# MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp) • [Level 0](https://w3schools.in/csharp-tutorial) • [Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm) • [Level 2](https://tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-tutorials) • [Level 3](https://guru99.com/c-sharp-tutorial.html) • [Level 4](https://geeksforgeeks.org/csharp-programming-language) • Good Books

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the `StreamWriter` in the scope of the `while` loop. Outside of it it does not exist. Try defining the StreamWriter as a parameter part of the class and only assign it later.

Change this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
```

To This:

```
static StreamReader sr = null;
static StreamWriter sw = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    
    while (true){
    
        ...
        sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    }
}
```